# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' but several times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am experiencing strange problem with spring MVC.

When I open root page on my project I see:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

It is ok, because I haven't mapped anything to the root...but problem that I am getting this error 3 times in a row like this.

```
фев 27, 2015 12:41:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
фев 27, 2015 12:41:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
фев 27, 2015 12:41:45 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd">



<!--<listener>-->
    <!--<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>-->
<!--</listener>-->
<!--<context-param>-->
    <!--<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
    <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/config.xml</param-value>-->
<!--</context-param>-->


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="ua.macko"/>
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>

       <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="username" value="root"/>
              <property name="password" value="****"/>
              <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
              <property name="annotatedClasses">
                     <list>
                            <value>ua.macko.dto.User</value>
                     </list>
              </property>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                     <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show.sql">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>


                     </props>
              </property>


       </bean>

       <bean id="userDao" class="ua.macko.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id = "transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
       </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Please advise what is wrong here.

Comment: Whats in your spring config, and how is your action defined?

Comment: @farrellmr I've added spring configuration file

Comment: remove sitemesh for the moment - and see if you can serve a helloworld.jsp

Comment: @farrellmr I've commented sitemesh filter but there is no result

Comment: Ok - I think your configuration is fine - what is your controller like? Do you have a mapping for /

Comment: Do you have a @RequestMapping(value = "/") mapping

Comment: @farrellmr no...I wrote in description: "I haven't mapped anything to the root..."

Comment: Sorry I missed that - but thats the problem. As a test add a root RequestMapping. Sorry for missing that

Comment: @farrellmr The thing is not about mapping. Even if I make mapping the request is made 3 times in a row.